# How to call WKWebView's evaluateJavaScript method

Tags: javascript, ios, nativescript

I'm trying to call a native WKWebView method, but nativescript keeps saying that the `evaluateJavaScript` function is undefined.

How should I try calling that function?

Here's the code I'm trying to run

```
console.log(nativeView.ios.evaluateJavaScript('document.URL', () => console.log('Hello, world')));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler` is the valid method name, it's documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc).

You may verify the callback for any errors before accessing the result.

```
webView.ios.evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler(jsStr,
            function (
                result,
                error
            ) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log("error...");
                    return;
                }
                console.log(result);
            });
```

If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Where did you get evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler from?
I'm unable to run the code above at all. Nativescript says that evaluateJavaScript is undefined.

Comment: It seems to work when i use evaluateJavaScriptCompletionHandler instead of evaluateJavaScript. Do you know why that is? Where did you find that function name from?

Comment: It's documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415017-evaluatejavascript?language=objc).

Comment: Ah okay. I was reading the docs wrong then. I've never touched Obj-C. Thanks a bunch!